# React-Native-error in installing navigation module

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to react native i used a code from below site for understanding navigation: 
1.https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Hello%20React%20Navigation%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.1.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.3.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.1.6%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.1.6%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.2.6%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E0.7.3%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.4.0&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fpop-to-top.js

But sadly struck with an error in Mac: the error shown was :
1.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDVOp.png)

I request to clear this issue.

Comment: i used following command to install nativation:
1.npm install @react-navigation/native
2.npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
3.npm install @react-navigation/stack

Comment: Can any one suggest a code to understand navigation.It will be nice.....